# Kendo Grid Edit form - Changing control value programmatically is ignored on submit

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm using Telerik Kendo UI Professional.  I have a grid with an edit template, and several controls on it.  I ran into a weird little requirement, where I needed to programmatically set the value of one of the controls, based on another control being changed.  The actual change of value seems to happen just fine.  However, when I submit the form to save changes, the new, programmatically-set value is ignored; it sends the original value instead.  If the user changes the value himself, the new value is submitted just fine.

Here is a sample:

http://dojo.telerik.com/@wittca/otoxO

This is not my original code, but it shows the same problem.  In this version, upon opening the edit popup, I programmatically modify the value of the UnitsInStock KendoNumericTextBox.  Then when I save the form, I would expect to see the new value, but I still see the old value in the grid.  So it does not take the programmatically-generated new value.

My original code is trying to set the value of a KendoComboBox, when one of the other controls changes, and the same situation happens.  I didn't have time to create the exact same situation, but most likely if we can fix that dojo sample, the same fix would apply to my ComboBox.

Comment: Please provide your actual code.  It is hard to give any solution with a generic working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the response I got from Telerik support:

You will need to trigger the change event as well, as the Grid listens for it in order to update the value. Please see the updated example here:

http://dojo.telerik.com/UjUkE

```
var units = e.container.find("[name='UnitsInStock']").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
units.value( <insert new value here> );
units.trigger("change");
```

The key line of code is that last one; that manually triggers the "change" event on the control, which forces the Grid to update the value.

This fix also works with my original problem involving ComboBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

He is a solution for you:

If you change the edit function that you have from:

```
 edit: function (e) {
     var units = e.container.find("[name='UnitsInStock']").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
     var unitsValue = units.value();
     units.value(unitsValue+1);
}
```

to this:

```
  edit: function (e) {
                         var val = e.model.UnitsInStock; 
                          e.model.set("UnitsInStock", val+ 1); 
                        }
```

It will bind the updated value for you.

Here is my updated code for you to test:

http://dojo.telerik.com/OHaKA/2